# Structure guidelines not showing in some XAML editor windows

Tags: visual-studio, xaml

VS Pro 2019... I have two sessions open, different projects, each with some C# and XAML code tabs, problem is in one of the XAML editor tabs..

In one window, XAML structure guidelines are shown... in the other window - not.
Yes I have checked the Options/Text Editor/General/Show structure guide lines... it is definitely checked in BOTH windows.

In the problem session, I get structure guides shown in my C# code tab just fine... but the XAML tab refuses to obey the checkbox.

I'm stumped as to why...

Thanks in advance for any help